# How to get selected values from different drop downs and populate those values in text boxes depeding on their ID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a valuation website using PHP, MYSQL, a bit of JQUERY and JavaScript. In my database I have 3 tables:

**Table "car_make":**

```
id make
1  BMW
```

**Table "model":**

```
model_id model_name make_id
1        M3         1
```

**Table "car_attributes":**

```
car_id make_id model_id year mileage cylinder price market_value
1      1       1        2019 5000    3.6      5000  5200
```

In the user's page I have different drop downs where the user can select the makes, models, year, mileage, cylinder and son on. Once the user has made all the selections from the drop downs and the user clicks the evaluate button, I want to get the price,value and other results of that specific car only based on the ID of the car_attributes and populate those values in text boxes. I have done the code using javascript but it only returns records of for example the year when the onchange event is trigger. here is the code I have so far.

```
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="get_car_year">Year</label>
       <select name="get_car_year" class="form-control item_category" 
           id="get_car_year" onchange="getDetails()">
          <option value="0">-- Select --</option>

           <?php

            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT year, price_in_ead, current_rate_dollar 
              from car_attributes ORDER BY year DESC";

           $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
               echo "<option data-price_in_ead='$row[1]'  data- 
             rate_in_dollar='$row[2]'  value='$row[0]'> $row[0] </option>";
           }

           ?>

        </select>
    </div>

<script>

    function getDetails(){
        var price = $('#get_car_year').find(':selected').data('price_in_ead');
        var rate = $('#get_car_year').find(':selected').data('rate_in_dollar');
        $('#price_in_ead').val(price);
        $('#rate_in_dollar').val(rate);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Upon Changing the year what happens now?. Did you use console.log for price and rate in getDetails?. Also update your question with the `price_in_ead`,`rate_in_dollar` form fields

Comment: When a selected a year from the drop down it shows the values like price and market value, but the problem is if the user then selects for example mileage, I need to create an onchange event for that also and all the other dropdowns. I want to show the values in textboxes when the user makes all the selections from the drop downs and clicks a button.

Comment: why you dont send ajax with current car_id to DB to get whole information  ?

Comment: @Ivan that is what I had in mind, but right now I don't have a clue on how to do that,  could you please give me an example

Comment: @EmanuelGoncalves check my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is example how can be done with ajax , you can rework it for ur use

```
<form class=""  method="post">
<select class="" name="makes">
<!-- values are id of makes from DB -->
<option value="1">BMW</option>
<option value="2">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class="" name="model">
<!-- values are id of model from DB -->
<option value="1">M3</option>
<option value="2">Q7</option>
</select>

<select class="" name="year">
<!-- values are year of yeas from DB -->
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Ajax

```
$('form').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'url',
data :  $('#form').serialize(),
success: function(data){
  $('textarea').append(data.year)
}
})
})
```

PHP

escape data 1st for security

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM car_attributes WHERE cat_id='". (int)$_POST['makes'] ."' AND year='". (int)$_POST['year'] ."'";
```

execute query and than return result

```
echo json_encode($query);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Do not escape it!

Comment: @Ivan thank you for that solution, might be just what I needed. I just have a few questions, the #form tag, i am guessing that is the ID of the form, and where the $('textarea') element is can I put the ID of a textbox. One last thing when you echo json_encode($query), it echos the query as it is and not values returned from the query. Do I need to loop through the array to return the results from the query?

Comment: @EmanuelGoncalves You need to prepare the query, execute and fetch the data. Better use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for database connection.

Comment: @EmanuelGoncalves yes form is the id of the form and textarea is the element where will be place the output , yes value is not returned becasue i forget to add execute method for the query , if you have any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` like this and in HTML custom data don't use any symbols, it should be in short.

Don't use like this `data-price_in_ead`, use like this `data-priceead`

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="get_car_year">Year</label>
       <select name="get_car_year" class="form-control item_category" 
           id="get_car_year" onchange="$('#price_in_ead').val($('#get_car_year').find(':selected').data('priceead'));$('#rate_in_dollar').val($('#get_car_year').find(':selected').data('ratedollar'));  ">
          <option value="0">-- Select --</option>

           <?php

            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT year, price_in_ead, current_rate_dollar 
              from car_attributes ORDER BY year DESC";

           $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
               echo "<option data-priceead='$row[1]'  data-ratedollar='$row[2]'  value='$row[0]'> $row[0] </option>";
           }

           ?>

        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer @DroidDev, it will work as you made it shorter. But my problem I don't want to use the onchange event to get the values of a single dropdown. I want to make a selection of all the dropdowns at once as I have multiples drop downs and populate their values in textboxes with a button click or maybe on form submission.